# line splitter from stdout to stdin

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

I am new at C programing, and i was asked to build a simple line splitter,
that receives a sentence input from the user (in the stdin), and print it again in the stdout (without saving the whole sentence) and skips one line ("\n") if "@" or "*" were typed in.
(also they want each sentence to start with its line number).
I completed the program and it works great, except one little thing:
for every input I try the first letter is lost.
the rest is done as I was required.

can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char cInput;
    int i = 1;
    int moreData = 1;

    printf( "line_splitter, please enter a sentence:\n");
    fflush(stdout); 
    cInput = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("%c: ", i);
    i=i+1;


/*while not end of file read to avoid error*/   
    while(!feof(stdin) && moreData){
    cInput = fgetc(stdin);
    fputc(cInput,stdout);
    switch(cInput){
        case '@':
        case '*':
            printf("\n");
            printf("%d: ", i);
            i=i+1;
        break;
        case '\n':
            moreData = 0;
        default:
            break;
    }
     }
     printf( "\ndone!\n");

  return 0; 
}
```

EDIT:
thank you all, i made it :)

Comment: Did you mean to use `%d` instead of `%c` in the second `printf`?

Comment: yes its for the line count, not for the receved input

Comment: `default:break;` isn't needed remove it.

Comment: Worthwhile background read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after you use `fflush`, you read a character.  That character is never printed/processed.  Remove that read and then update your while loop to

```
while((cInput = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && moreData)
```

Make sure you redeclare cInput as an `int` which is the correct return type from fgetc.

Comment: And remove the `fgetc` in the `while` loop.

Comment: the while loop change you said i did, but when i changed cInput to int, it didnt print my sentence as it should =/

Comment: I tried the same change and it worked.  Only problem I had was I had to fix the printf mentioned above by CG and the "1:" came up on screen too early.